# Test Class for Extension including a SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

I wrote the following class and it does what I expect it do on the vf page in Sandbox and so I  started a test class but then my lack of apex knowledge and coding experience caught up with me.  Please let me know what I need to do to get a test class written.  Below is my code:

```
public class DandBController
{  
    private ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl {get; set;}
    public List<D_B_Reports__c> dbreport {get;set;}


    public DandBController(ApexPages.StandardController std) 
    {
       stdCtrl=std;
       setupdb();
    }


    private void setupdb()
    {
        dbreport=[SELECT X24_Month_Paydex__c, 3_Month_Paydex__c, Comments__c, Company__c, Credit_Score_Class__c, D_B_Rating__c,  Financial_Stress__c, Most_Recent_Report__c, Other__c, Report_Date__c, UCC_Filings__c
                  FROM D_B_Reports__c 
                  WHERE Company__c=:stdCtrl.getId() 
                  ORDER BY  Report_Date__c DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1 ];
    }
}
```

And the beginnings of my test class is as follows:

```
@isTest
private class TestDBController 
{ 
  static testMethod void TestDBControllerMethod()
  {
      Date lastDayOfMonth = Date.today();
          lastDayOfMonth = lastDayOfMonth.toStartOfMonth().addDays(-1);

      //Insert Account
      Account acct = new Account(Name='TestClassAccount', RecordTypeID='012a0000001C2BF');
      insert acct;

      // Retrieve the new Account
      acct = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id =:acct.Id];

      //Insert DBReport
      D_B_Reports__c d = new D_B_Reports__c (Company__c=acct.ID, Report_Date__c=lastDayOfMonth );
      insert d;

     //Retrieve the new DBReport
      d = [Select Id, Name,Report_Date__c FROM D_B_Reports__c WHERE Id =:d.Id];

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next steps are explained in the comments of the below code:

```
// Create an instance of the standard controller with your DBReport record
// I guess the standard controller is on that object
ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(d);
// Create an instance of your extension
DandBController controller = new DandBController(stdController);
// Ensure that the constructor got called and executed the setupdb() method
system.assertNotEquals(controller.dbreport, null); // ensure list is not null
system.assertEquals(controller.dbreport.size(), 1); // ensure list is not empty and has 1 record
system.assertEquals(controller.dbreport[0].Report_Date__c, lastDayOfMonth); // ensure the record in the list matches the values from your test method
```

You don't need this line:

```
//Retrieve the new DBReport
d = [Select Id, Name,Report_Date__c FROM D_B_Reports__c WHERE Id =:d.Id];
```

The record that you need to check is now `controller.dbreport[0]`

Comment: Thanks Bachovski.  I added your lines but it threw a compile error on the system.assert - Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<D_B_Reports__c> at line 26 column 21.  What does that mean?

Comment: Ah I didn't see that your variable is actually a list :) I've updated my question. Please note that I wrote this code on the fly in order to guide you in the right direction. There are plenty of online resources that you can read and learn from in regards to how to write test methods.